# The derivative of the multiplication of a matrix and a vector with respect to a matrix

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

For simplicity, suppose I have a $3\times3$ matrix $M$ and two vectors $u,v$ of size $3$. Let $F(M,u)=Mu$. I know that
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial F(M,u)}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial Mu}{\partial u}=M.
\end{equation}
Then what the result of 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial F(M,u)}{\partial M}=\frac{\partial Mu}{\partial M}
\end{equation}
Is there a special name for it? And how do I compute the following equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial Mu}{\partial M}v
\end{equation}

Basically, my second question is equivalent how to do multiplication between a $3\times3\times3$ matrix and a vector.